# Background Color, ForegroundColor

Tags: c#, console, background-foreground

I'm Junior programmer I Wrote this Code in Console application

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
    Console.WriteLine("backgroundcolor is red");
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
    Console.Write("ForegroundColor is Green");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

But I want to Write one console write line. So background color is red just with background color in console and Foreground Color is Green write in console application  just with Foreground Color at a same time that each sentence effected with its class in one line.

Comment: Then try setting both background and foreground color before your first writeline.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about this...

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
 var originalColor = Console.BackgroundColor;
 Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
 Console.Write("The background color is red. ");
 Console.BackgroundColor = originalColor;
 Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
 Console.Write("The foreground color is green");
 Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: I want to write background color is red just effected with background color and foreground color is green just with foreground color

Comment: Can you write this code with one system.console.writeline("");

Comment: sorry but my mean is write one console.writeline  something like that system.console.writelin("{0},{1} "..........)

Comment: @BehdadBitimax I updated my answer. See if that fixes it, and remember; If it helps, upvote it!

Comment: ok,sure,thank you very much for follow my post and answered my question

Answer (score 1):

I think is what you want. Correct me if I am wrong.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var originalColor = Console.BackgroundColor;
        Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
        Console.WriteLine("The BackgroundColor is " + Console.BackgroundColor.ToString() + " and the ForegroundColor is " + Console.ForegroundColor.ToString());
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

I think this will fix your problem.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Can you tell me how you want to do it based off my code I posted? 

EDIT: I just realized that MailmanOdd's answer worked for you.

Comment: I don't follow, sorry.

Comment: my mean is "background color is red "just with red effect(console.backgroundcolor),and foreground color is green effect with green  console.ForegroundColor

Comment: Oh, you want it to post the background color that it currently is? And not a set message?

Comment: for example I have two Text,text1 and text2

Comment: text1 =Console.backgroundcolor=red

Comment: text2=console.foregroundcolor=green ,in console.writeline

Comment: Check my updated code. I think I figured out what you needed.

Comment: Oh my God, in your code text1 and text2 all show with background color red and foreground color green.

Comment: Isn't that what you wanted? Background color is red, Foreground color is green, and it posts the background color and foreground color.

Comment: sorry no,can you run 
 
MailmanOdd code at the top of page,it is correct but need to edit to write one console.writeline

Comment: This does only write one Console.WriteLine. I really don't think you even know what you want. I have been spending a lot of time trying to help you, and you want what I have posted, but you say it isn't right... Can you explain exactly what you want?

Comment: please calm down,i know what i want,if i had 10 reputation i would have sent my picture,in first  MailmanOdd,did you see MailmanOdd  code?this is really correct,did you run that? i want this code  was written whit one syntax console.writeline("{1},{2}"   ....,.....)

Comment: So you want his code, but you want it to run the code I made that does this: `Console.WriteLine("The BackgroundColor is " + Console.BackgroundColor.ToString() + " and the ForegroundColor is " + Console.ForegroundColor.ToString());`?

Comment: you wrote just one console.writeline yes ,but when i run this code text1 and text2 at the same time all of theme in background red and foreground green,but I need at the same time text1 just with background red and text 2 with no background just with foreground

Comment: I don't understand at all what you want, sorry.

Comment: BTW, for the time I took to help you, would you mind upvoting my answer?